# JAVA-Assertion fails even expected output seems to be matching with the actual output. Please help me out with the possible solutions

Tags: java, android, visual-studio-code, project, object-oriented-analysis

This is the result of Integration testing!

Message:
N/A
Stack trace:
org.opentest4j.AssertionFailedError: **expected**: <Songs Loaded successfully
1 Kiran

Playlist ID - 1

Playlist ID - 2

Delete Successful

Current Song Playing

Song - South of the Border

Album - No.6 Collaborations Project

Artists - Ed Sheeran,Cardi.B,Camilla Cabello

Playlist ID - 1

Playlist Name - MY_PLAYLIST_1

Song IDs - 1 4 5 6 7

Playlist ID - 1

Playlist Name - MY_PLAYLIST_1

Song IDs - 1 4 5 6

Current Song Playing

Song - Cross Me

Album - No.6 Collaborations Project

Artists - Ed Sheeran,Chance The Rapper,PnB Rock

Current Song Playing

Song - Give Life Back To Music

Album - Random Access Memories

Artists - Daft Punk,Nile Rodgers

Current Song Playing

Song - South of the Border

Album - No.6 Collaborations Project

Artists - Ed Sheeran,Cardi.B,Camilla Cabello

Current Song Playing

Song - Give Life Back To Music

Album - Random Access Memories

Artists - Daft Punk,Nile Rodgers

Current Song Playing

Song - Cross Me

Album - No.6 Collaborations Project

Artists - Ed Sheeran,Chance The Rapper,PnB Rock

Given song id is not a part of the active playlist>

**but was:** <Songs Loaded successfully

1 Kiran

Playlist ID - 1

Playlist ID - 2

Delete Successful

Current Song Playing

Song - South of the Border

Album - No.6 Collaborations Project

Artists - Ed Sheeran,Cardi.B,Camilla Cabello

Playlist ID - 1

Playlist Name - MY_PLAYLIST_1

Song IDs - 1 4 5 6 7

Playlist ID - 1

Playlist Name - MY_PLAYLIST_1

Song IDs - 1 4 5 6

Current Song Playing

Song - Cross Me

Album - No.6 Collaborations Project

Artists - Ed Sheeran,Chance The Rapper,PnB Rock

Current Song Playing

Song - Give Life Back To Music

Album - Random Access Memories

Artists - Daft Punk,Nile Rodgers

Current Song Playing

Song - South of the Border

Album - No.6 Collaborations Project

Artists - Ed Sheeran,Cardi.B,Camilla Cabello

Current Song Playing

Song - Give Life Back To Music

Album - Random Access Memories

Artists - Daft Punk,Nile Rodgers

Current Song Playing

Song - Cross Me

Album - No.6 Collaborations Project

Artists - Ed Sheeran,Chance The Rapper,PnB Rock

Given song id is not a part of the active playlist>

```
at org.junit.jupiter.api.AssertionUtils.fail(AssertionUtils.java:55)
at org.junit.jupiter.api.AssertionUtils.failNotEqual(AssertionUtils.java:62)
at org.junit.jupiter.api.AssertEquals.assertEquals(AssertEquals.java:182)
at org.junit.jupiter.api.AssertEquals.assertEquals(AssertEquals.java:177)
at org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertEquals(Assertions.java:1124)
at com.crio.jukebox.AppTest.runTest1(AppTest.java:71)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
at org.junit.platform.commons.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtils.java:688)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.MethodInvocation.proceed(MethodInvocation.java:60)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain$ValidatingInvocation.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:131)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.intercept(TimeoutExtension.java:149)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.interceptTestableMethod(TimeoutExtension.java:140)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.interceptTestMethod(TimeoutExtension.java:84)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker$ReflectiveInterceptorCall.lambda$ofVoidMethod$0(ExecutableInvoker.java:115)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.lambda$invoke$0(ExecutableInvoker.java:105)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain$InterceptedInvocation.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:106)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:64)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.chainAndInvoke(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:45)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.invoke(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:37)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.invoke(ExecutableInvoker.java:104)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.invoke(ExecutableInvoker.java:98)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeTestMethod$6(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:210)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.invokeTestMethod(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:206)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:131)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:65)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$5(NodeTestTask.java:139)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$7(NodeTestTask.java:129)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:127)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:126)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:84)
at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1541)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:38)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$5(NodeTestTask.java:143)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$7(NodeTestTask.java:129)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:127)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:126)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:84)
at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1541)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:38)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$5(NodeTestTask.java:143)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$7(NodeTestTask.java:129)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:127)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:126)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:84)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.submit(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:32)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:57)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestEngine.execute(HierarchicalTestEngine.java:51)
at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:248)
at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.lambda$execute$5(DefaultLauncher.java:211)
at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.withInterceptedStreams(DefaultLauncher.java:226)
at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:199)
at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:141)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit5.runner.JUnit5TestReference.run(JUnit5TestReference.java:98)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:40)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:529)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:756)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:452)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:210)
```

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: What you are sharing doesn't help to understand the problem. If the assertion is failing, it's because the two objects are not "equals" (equals being the equals of the class itself, not their string representation that you see in the output). You should rather share how the objects are build and how the comparison is performed.

Comment: Thanks @MatteoNNZ for helping to solve this assertion failing issue. It worked and yes, also thanks for reminding me about this concept.